# problem with constant variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

Variable x is supposed to be constant, but the program calculates for each variable x, 100 numbers of x. I want all my x variables to have the same definition, but the program constantly changes each x variable's definition.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqOJ6xqR2PKjglEgVfbcNx8XyKX5?e=SdAOHZ

Comment: Your definition `x=Table[...]` creates a list  called `x`. Please clarify what you want to calculate!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I've understood your NB, but probably this is what you want:

```
ddQ2[x_] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(x\), \(1\)]\(z \((1 - 
z)\)*\((0.288554*\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \*FractionBox[\(x\), \(z\)])\), \(0.435 - 
1\)]/\*SqrtBox[FractionBox[\(x\), \(z\)]])\) \[DifferentialD]z\)\)
```

Then make `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[ddQ2[#] & /@ Table[j/100, {j, 1, 100}],PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: Equivalent in `InputForm`. `ddQ2[x_] = 
 Integrate[
  z*(1 - z)*(0.288554*((1 - x/z)^(0.435 - 1)/Sqrt[x/z])), {z, x, 1}]`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Table[j/100, {j, 1, 100}];
```

Since `x` is a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html), [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the integration onto the `List`. Since you are using inexact numbers, [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) is as good as [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) and is much faster.

```
{#, Integrate[z*(1 - z)*(0.288554*((1 - #/z)^(0.435 - 1)/
                Sqrt[#/z])), {z, #, 1}]} &[1/2] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.524199, {1/2, 0.0838901}} *)

{#, NIntegrate[z*(1 - z)*(0.288554*((1 - #/z)^(0.435 - 1)/
                Sqrt[#/z])), {z, #, 1}]} &[1/2] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.007069, {1/2, 0.0838901}} *)

 ddQ2 = {#, NIntegrate[z*(1 - z)*(0.288554*((1 - #/z)^(0.435 - 1)/
                 Sqrt[#/z])), {z, #, 1}]} & /@ x;

ListPlot[ddQ2, AxesLabel -> {"x", "ddQ2"}]
```

[image]